# Material UI X Date Calendar/Picker : Override Default Props and Style

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x

I'm using Material UI X for date pickers and usually, I use the createTheme function from Material UI for global styling. I'm looking to extend that ease of customization to MUI X components, so I don't have to individually tweak styles or props every time. Is there a streamlined way to apply global theme settings to MUI X, similar to "createTheme," so any changes automatically reflect across all components?

What I want to do is something like this :

```
const customTheme = createTheme({
    components: {
       MuiDateCalendar: {
          defaultProps: {// MY COMPONENT PROPS },
          styleOverrides: { // MY COMPONENT STYLE }
       }
    }
})
```

Thanks a lot for any advice!